Padrino framework admin panel
When i use padrino admin.
ArgumentError at /admin/ wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

 <li class=navbar-edit-account><%= link_to tag_icon(:user), url(:accounts, :edit, :id => current_account.id), :title => pat(:profile), :class => 'navbar-nav-link' %></li>

I thing something about pat helper is wrong?
Please help..
C:/Sites/padrino-sites/blog-tutorial/admin/views/sessions/new.erb in __tilt_59120
    <title><%= @title.present? ? "#{@title} | Padrino Admin" : "#{pat('login.title')} | Padrino Admin" %></title>
C:/Sites/padrino-sites/blog-tutorial/admin/controllers/sessions.rb in block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
    render "/sessions/new", nil, :layout => false
C:/Sites/padrino-sites/blog-tutorial/lib/connection_pool_management_middleware.rb in block in call
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection { @app.call(env) }
C:/Sites/padrino-sites/blog-tutorial/lib/connection_pool_management_middleware.rb in call
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection { @app.call(env) }


Yes,i did......

The top section of code (referring to a link_to in an li tag) does not match the bottom section of code (referring to the contents of a title tag) so now I have no idea which location you are referring to as causing the error. pat itself cannot be causing the error you are reporting because you are not passing 2 arguments to it, in either location but you are going to need to clarify the question as I fear the update has only added confusion.

When i delete pat there is not a single error
